# can I create a custom route without using redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Loginscreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Login from './Login';

class Loginscreen extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      username:'',
      password:'',
      loginscreen:[],
      loginmessage:'',
      isLogin:true
    }
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    var loginscreen=[];
    loginscreen.push(<Login parentContext={this} appContext={this.props.parentContext}/>);
    this.setState({
                  loginscreen:loginscreen
                    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="loginscreen">
        {this.state.loginscreen}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const style = {
  margin: 15,
};
export default Loginscreen;
```

and I have Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Form, Grid, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import axios from 'axios';
import validator from 'Validator';
import InlineError from './components/messages/InlineError';
import UploadScreen from './UploadScreen';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class Login extends Component {
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state={
    email:'',
    password:'',
    errors: {}
  }
 }

 onChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
 }

 validate = () => {
   if (!this.state.password) this.state.errors.password = "Can't be blank";
   if (!this.state.email) this.state.errors.email = "Invalid Email";
   return this.state.errors;
 }
 onSubmit = (e) => {
  const errors = this.validate(this.state);
  this.setState({ errors });
  e.preventDefault();
  var apiBaseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login";
  var self = this;
  var payload={
      "email":this.state.email,
      "password":this.state.password
  }
  var config = {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    withCredentials: false
  }

  axios.post(apiBaseUrl, payload, config)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    if(response.status == 200){
        console.log("Login successful");
    }
    else if(response.status == 204){
        console.log("Username password do not match");
        alert("username password do not match")
    }
    else{
        console.log("Username does not exists");
        alert("Username does not exist");
    }
})
.catch(function (error) {
console.log(error);
});
}

render() {
      const { email, password, errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className='login-form'>
      <style>{`
        body > div,
        body > div > div,
        body > div > div > div.login-form {
          height: 100%;
        }
      `}</style>
      <Grid textAlign='center' style={{ height: '100%' }} verticalAlign='middle'>
        <Grid.Column style={{ maxWidth: 450 }}>
        <br />
        <br />
          <Form size='large' onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <Segment stacked>
              <Form.Input 
              type='text'
              name='email'
              value={email}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              fluid 
              icon='user' 
              iconPosition='left' 
              placeholder='E-mail address' 
              />
              { errors.email && <InlineError text={errors.email} />}
              <Form.Input
              type='password'
              name='password'
              value={password}
              onChange={this.onChange}              
              fluid
              icon='lock'
              iconPosition='left'
              placeholder='Password'
              />
              { errors.password && <InlineError text={errors.password} />}
              <Button fluid size='large' type="submit">
                Login
              </Button>
            </Segment>
          </Form>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
  }
}
const style = {
 margin: 15,
};
export default Login;
```

that returns:

[image]

can I use this response alone to be able to create a conditional statement that would create a custom route that can only be accessed if someone is logged in successfully?

this is my `app.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import LoginPage from "./Login";
import UploadScreen from "./UploadScreen";

const App = () => (
<div className="ui container"> 
  <Route path="/" exact component={LoginPage} />
  <Route path="/upload" exact component={UploadScreen} />
</div>
);
export default App;
```

I want that "/upload" route to only be accessible if someone is logged in. can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to make public and private routes:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest, loggedIn }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      (loggedIn ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: LOGIN,
            state: { from: props.location },
          }}
        />
      ))
    }
  />
);

const PublicRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest, loggedIn}) => (
  <Route
  {...rest}
  render={props =>
    (!loggedIn ? (
      <Component {...props} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: HOME,
          state: { from: props.location },
        }}
      />
    ))
  }
/> 
)
```